# Spring Security - Thymeleaf - Can I evaluate SPEL Expressions inside sec:authorize tags?

Tags: java, security, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

i am writing a little Spring MVC - Spring Security Web Application with Thymeleaf as Front-End-Technology.

I use Role Based Authorization in the Front-End with the Security Taglib such as:

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
```

This works pretty good.

But what I also want to do is to send Informations via the Controller to the View:

```
model.addAttribute("Key", "Value");
```

e.g.

```
model.addAttribute("isAllowed", true);
```

and then use it in the Front-End inside the "sec:authorize" such as:

```
<div sec:authorize="${isAllowed}">
```

But then I get an:

Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.dialect.processor.AuthorizeAttrProcessor

Is my approach possible ? What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The sec:authorize tag only works on a restricted set of expressions (examples here: https://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/02/26/spring-security-part-v-security-tags/). You are adding an attribute manually, which can be accessed like this using thymeleaf:

```
<div th:if="${isAllowed}">
    Content here
</div>
```